# spreadsheet: sorting by the first n characters of the entries of a column then by another column

Tags: openoffice, sorting, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

Is there any way to sort an OpenOffice Calc spreadsheet by the **first n characters** of a given column then by another criterion?

For example suppose that we have the following 4*2 spreadsheet (Note that all of characters are of text type, not necessary numbers)

```
124  2
144  3
127  1
139  4
```

For example I would like to sort (Ascending) by the first 2 characters of the first column then by the second column (Ascending).

The output should be:

```
127  1
124  2
139  4
144  3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make a third column (hidden if need be) which is just the left n characters of the first column. ie. `LEFT(column; n)`

Then you can sort by that column followed by your second column.

Comment: Alternatively, build the entire sort key in the helper column: `LEFT(column1, n) & column2`. Note that the parameter delimiter in functions like `LEFT` may be either comma (`,`) or semicolon (`;`) based on your lo0cale.